# Android Webview rendering when used together with menudrawer

Tags: android, webview

We are using the generally excellent [Android menudrawer](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer) library to do a slideout menu to the left of our app. This works great for all views apart from Webviews, who produce various rendering issues when the menu is slid back and forth, like this:

[image: Rendering problem 1]
[image: Rendering problem 2]

When you tap the webview it corrects itself and the page looks fine again until you slide the menu out.

What is causing this and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a hardware layer issue. Switching to software rendering of the WebView works around the problem, at the cost of significantly worse rendering performance. That is acceptable for our purposes.

I added this to the Webview in my layout:

```
android:layerType="software"
```

Comment: This is very useful but i wonder if it effects performance or not.

Comment: i had the same issue where in webview i was playing a video but using android:layerType="software" my webview resizing while sliding menu got resolved but it does't show the video only voice i could hear and whole webview displayed black screen.

Comment: @alicanbatur : please give any feedback over my above post.